# Trigger left mouseup with jQuery

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I try to trigger the mouseup event with jQuery. But I want to bind to this event the fact that this is a left click. This fact is checked in another function :

```
$('body').mouseup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1)
        ...
}
```

So I cannot just do `$('body').mouseup();`.

I've looked at the documentation of `mouseup`but I haven't found the solution. Do you know it please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an [`Event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object yourself, and then call [`.trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) on it.

```
// Create a new mouse up object with 'which' specified to be 1.
var e = $.Event( "mouseup", { which: 1 } );
// Triggers it on the body.
$("body").trigger(e);
```

**Note**, I'm triggering on the body element, you were triggering on a div with ID=body. If this was intentional you'd need to change it from `"body"` to `"#body"` like in your code.

Comment: `body` was just an example. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I don't seem to be having the same problem with binding the mouseup event to either the left or the right button click. I have created a test in jsfiddle that you can reference.

```
$('body').mouseup(function(e){
if (e.which === 1){
//left click stuff here
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7J6ew/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a great English speaker, but you haven't understood my question.

Comment: Apologies, looking back at the question, I understand what you're asking. In that case, Benjamin's answer is excellent!